# Brand new to Python - Crash Course

Tags: python-3.x

I literally started this crash course book an hour ago and I am working on one of the first "Try It Yourself" activities and what it wants me to do is very basic although I cannot figure out how to obtain the proper output.  I've read about storing information in a variable, printing that information, stripping whitespace from a string, and using \n and \t to make new lines that are tabbed.  The activity says "Store a person's name and include some whitespace characters at the beginning and the end of the name.  Make sure you use each character combination "\t" and "\n" at least once.  Print the name once so the whitespace around the name is displayed.  Then print the name using each of the three stripping functions, lstrip(), rstrip(), and strip().

```
full_name2 = " John Smith "
print(full_name2)
print("Whitespace Stripping:\n\t" + full_name2.rstrip())
```

The above code gives me the proper output of simply printing:

```
Whitespace Stripping:
         John Smith
```

How do I add the remaining functions lstrip() and strip() to print in two subsequent new lines under the first line resulting in something like this:

```
Whitespace Stripping:
         John Smith
        John Smith  
        John Smith
```

Comment: Try also to wrap the result by `repr()` like `print("Whitespace Stripping:\n\t" + repr(full_name2.rstrip()))` to see what happens. The function adds the quotes and converts some whitespaces back to sequences.

Comment: You should mark one of the answers as correct if you believe it answers your question. This means others won't waste time trying to answer it too.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you used `rstrip` will do it:

```
print("\t" + full_name2.lstrip())
print("\t" + full_name2.strip())
```

To highlight the white space you could surround the name with quotes:

```
print("\t'" + full_name2.lstrip() + "'")
```

---

**UPDATED**

The answer above was the simplest way to do it based on the code in the question. If I was doing it I would use variables and format a multiline string (for readability) like so:

```
full_name = " John Smith "

name_rstrip = full_name.rstrip()
name_lstrip = full_name.lstrip()
name_strip = full_name.strip()

print("""Whitespace Stripping:
\t'{name_rstrip}'
\t'{name_lstrip}'
\t'{name_strip}'""".format(**locals()))
```

which outputs:

```
Whitespace Stripping:
    ' John Smith'
    'John Smith '
    'John Smith'
```

Comment: I thought of that as well, I guess I was just stuck on putting all three functions in one line instead of using the "print" command on the new line myself...Something like

print("Whitespace Stripping:\n\t" + full_name2.rstrip()\n\t + full_name2.lstrip()\n\t + full_name2.strip())

but that didnt work....Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can do it all in one line like that but you'll need to put `+` after each call and put quotes around the newline tab characters `"\n\t"`. I just wanted to show you the simplest way in relation to what you've already learned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it John Keyes way, I would define each type as a variable so you can use it later:

```
full_name2 = " John Smith "
rstrip = ("\t" + full_name2.rstrip())
lstrip = ("\t" + full_name2.lstrip())
strip = ("\t" + full_name2.strip())
print(full_name2)
print("Whitespace Stripping:\n\t" + rstrip + lstrip + strip)
```

Comment: There is none, as this is not an error. `print` simply returns `None`. At least try your code before you post it.

Comment: Err, I'm sorry. Remove the `print` statement from the variables, as well as the parens

Comment: Thank you for your idea - It put me in the right direction...I edited your original post removing the duplicate print functions and was able to obtain the output needed...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Variable "person" is with whitespace on both sides. Using ".rstrip()", ".lstrip()" and "strip.()" removes whitespace. I have entered "Output:" and move it (tab) to the right using "\t" to be more readable. Each output is printed in a new line (using "\n").

```
person = ' Mike Tyson '
print(person)
person_rstrip = person.rstrip()
person_lstrip = person.lstrip()
person_strip = person.strip()
print('\tOutput:\n'+ person_rstrip + '\n' + person_lstrip + '\n' + person_strip)
```

And the result is:
[Assignment 2.7, Chapter 2, Python Crash Course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM6qr.gif)

Comment: Can you add some explanation etc. to your code. So when other people stumble across this answer they may understand it a bit better?

Comment: #Hayt   This is my answer to an assignment in book Python Crash Course, 2016 edition,  (Chapter 2, variables and simple data types, Try it yourself - assignment 2.7, stripping names). Assignment is: "Store a person’s name, and include some whitespace characters at the beginning and end of the name. Make sure you use each character combination, "\t" and "\n", at least once. Print the name once, so the whitespace around the name is displayed. Then print the name using each of the three stripping functions, lstrip(), rstrip(), and strip()." Best regards :)

Comment: I meant more.. hmm: imagine you would want to know those things and someone just puts the code in front of you. Some explanation to them or at least showing what they would do (like add the output) would be nice to help the understanding. Answers here should not only be for the person asking but for others who stumble across this question. Put some effort in your answer. It usually will be appreciated. Additions to your answer would also be better in your answer (you can edit it) instead of writing it in the comments